# How to chain match and replace regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
str="abc { return false;}"
```

I just want to get the word "false" from the string "str", as follows,

```
str.match(/return \w+;/g).replace(/return/,"")
```

It 's wrong ! 
How can I correct this expression to get the desired word?

Comment: I suppose, you want to remove(replace) the whole content within curly braces `{` `}`, right?

Comment: I want to get "false" in the curly braces

Comment: then what is `.replace(/return/,"")` for ? It will remove `return` word from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is just to extract the "returned value" from the string(function text definition) - it can be achieved through one operation without chaining:

```
var str = "abc { return true;}";
console.log(str.match(/return (\w+?);/)[1]); // outputs "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.match` will return an array with matching elements, not a single string. This is why `.replace` fails. A quick fix would be to add `[0]` to replace on the first array element like so: `str.match(/return \w+;/g)[0].replace(/return/,"")`

However, this will return `false;` (not exactly what you want) and it will fail when there's no match at all: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

A better way would be to use capture groups with paranthesis:

```
var str= "abc { return false;}"
var re = /return (\w+);/g
var results = re.exec(str);
```

The result is again an array with the first element being the complete match, the second element is the first capture group: `["return false;", "false", index: 6, input: "abc { return false;}"]`